# bounds of imageView are always 240

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a probably simple mistake that drives me crazy.
I'm working with UIImageView within a UIScrollView. To fit the image in the view I want to get the width of the imageView to adjust the zoom scale.
But the code

```
imageView.bounds.width
```

always returns 240.0 no matter what size the actual image has. 
In the Interface Builder the imageView is horizontally and verically centered in the view, clip subviews is true and Mode is aspect fit.
Any ideas?

Comment: How are you laying the view out? Are you using constraints or frames? Can we see this code or the constraints set in interface builder?

Comment: When are you accessing the width? If it's in `viewDidLoad` this value will always be your storyboard value. In `viewDidAppear` the actual frames and bounds of outlets have been set by the system and their values should change.

Comment: the dimensions of the image view will remain the same, no matter what the dimensions of the image is. are you sure you want to look at the bounding rectangle? (I think your question needs more detail to get helpful answers)

Comment: I'm using constraints in the interface builder. And the problem remains in viewDidAppear. It seems to be a general problem with my settings. I just created a new project with only one viewController and exactly the same constraints...here everything works normal. Nevertheless it would be great to find that bug in my settings as I've been working quite a while on it.

Comment: I found a kind of workaround. By copying the viewController from a new project in this project the problem does not appear anymore. Not an elegant solution...but it works. Thank you for your quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the `UIImageView` is not related to the size of the image it contains. The `UIImageView` is probably sized to 240.0 in the storyboard or wherever else you generate it. The image will scale down or up to fit the view based on the mode. To get the size of the actual *image*, try the following code:

```
let image = UIImage("my_image_file")
let imageHeight = image.size.height
let imageWidth = image.size.width
```

With the size of the image now know, you can set the size of the view appropriately.

Comment: Or just call `sizeToFit` on the image view after setting its image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Now I check the bounds in the main_queue and everything works fine.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     print(self.image.bounds.width)
 })
```